# Printf not printing out the expected result, why?

Tags: c, gcc, printf, output, getchar

I am programming in c on ubuntu terminal gcc compiler. printf is not giving any output. Please explain why.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int c;
    while (c = getchar() == EOF)
    {
        printf("%d\n", (int)c);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `while (c = getchar() == EOF)` --> `while ((c = getchar()) == EOF)`

Comment: No need to cast `c` to `int`, as promotion to `int` is done implicitly for variadic functions.

Comment: @alk Unclear: what implicit promotion to `int` are you referring to?

Comment: @chux: ... as promotion to `int` is done implicitly for parameters with a lower rank than `int` when being passed to a variadic functions.

Comment: @alk Yes agree what you say is true, but how does that apply here?  The only variable is `int c` and that is not lower rank than `int` and no promotion occurs.

Comment: @chux: Hu .. I see, yes. Nothing to promote around ... - naming a dog a cat (`int  c`) is confusing ... *sigh*

Answer (score 3):

```
 c = getchar() == EOF
```

means `c = (getchar() == EOF)` as the assignment expression is right-associative and has the lowest priority from all the expressions apart from comma-expression.

which means for your code, `c = 0` almost all the time. So the loop `while(0)` is not executed.

You mean  `while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)`.

Also, it is no need to cast `c` to `int` in

```
 printf("%d\n", (int)c);
```

because the `default argument promotions` do it automatically.

The correct code may be so:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int c;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
        printf("%d\n", c);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [Similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41447252/printf-not-giving-output-in-c?noredirect=1#comment70102660_41447252) for this answer: what is the promotion you are referring to with "because the default argument promotions do it automatically."?  Agree about the "no need to cast `int c` to `int`" part.

Answer (score 0):

To ammend the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41447285/2173917), see the [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) table.

The equality operator `==` has higher precedence over the assignment `=`, so in your case, first the equality check will take place and then the result will get assigned, which is what you don't want. So, a statement like

```
  (c = getchar() == EOF)
```

gets grouped like

```
  ( c = (getchar() == EOF) )
```

which is *wrong*.

> *Printf **not printing** out the expected result, why?*

To elaborate the ***no output*** part, in your case, the result of the comparison is either a 0 or 1. Related, quoting `C11`, chapter §6.5.9

> [...] Each of the operators yields 1 if the
>   specified relation is true and 0 if it is false. The result has type `int`. [...]

So, the assigned value is either `0` or `1`, and you try to print it using `%c` format specifier. This value(s) does not have a printable representation, thus you don't *see* any output.

FWIW, [here's a list of printable and non-printable values.](https://www.juniper.net/documentation/en_US/idp5.1/topics/reference/general/intrusion-detection-prevention-custom-attack-object-extended-ascii.html)

**Solution:** Make it explicit, using a pair of parenthesis to enforce the order of execution of the sub-expressions, like

```
 while ( (c = getchar()) != EOF )
```

That said,

- The conforming signature of `main()` is `int main(void)`, at at least in a hosted enviroment.
- The cast to `(int)` is superfluous, (*if in lesser rank than `int`*) the supplied argument is implicitly promoted, anyway.